# Error in coroutine while installing nvim-lua.planary.nvim with nvim 0.9.1

Tags: neovim, error, packer, plugin-telescope

I'm trying to setup my nvim environment following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7i4amO_zaE). I tried to install Telescope and got this error.
I'm installing this on wsl2, nvim version 0.9.1

```
[packer.nvim] [ERROR 18:23:00] async.lua:20: Error in coroutine: vim/_editor.lua:0: nvim_exec2()../home/minhnd/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/plenary.nvim/plugin/plenary.vim, line 1: Vim:E492: Not an editor command: ^M
```

[image: Error image]

This is my packer.lua file:

```
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'

  use {
    'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.2',
  -- or                            , branch = '0.1.x',
    requires = { {'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'} }
  }
end)
```

Comment: Could be [this neovim issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/331) about DOS line ending. Sadly, we cannot know for sure because the guy who opened the bug posted a now defunct image of the error message instead of writing it in text. Oh, the irony...

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/) You can [edit] to include the exact error text

Comment: Convert your `.vim` files to unix file format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thanks to Christian Brabandt's comment.
Here's what I did for those who might get the same error:

I cd to the error file, open it with nvim, run `:set ff=unix` then save the file and the error is gone.